# Java jdom2 problems with creating xml

Tags: java, android, jdom-2

I want to create Element for android permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

I try something like this:

```
Element el = new Element("uses-permission", "android:name", "android.permission.);
rootNode.addContent(el);
```

This throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jdom2.IllegalNameException: The name "android:name" is  not legal for JDOM/XML Namespace prefixs: XML name 'android:name' cannot contain the character ":".
```

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `android` namespace prefix on the root element of the XML document, then add the name attribute using the same namespace.

```
Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace( "android" );
Element e = new Element( "uses-permission", ns );
e.setAttribute( "name", "android.permission.INTERNET", ns );
```

Comment: Thanks, your respond was very helpful. I need this one      `Namespace ns = rootNode.getNamespace("android");
Element e = new Element("uses-permission");
e.setAttribute("name", "android.permission." + permissionForInsert, ns);`